# Cannot read property '$broadcast' of undefined in AngularJS Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine2.0

I am getting error while writing Angular JS Jasmine Unit Test cases:-

**Cannot read property '$broadcast' of undefined**

My Code:-

```
    $scope.$on('getVersionData', function (event, data) {
    getVersion(data.RegistrationId, data.FacilityCode);
});
```

My UnitTest Code

```
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $injector) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

}));
it('Controller: getVersion: Checking if $scope variable set to expectedValues', function () {
    $rootScope('getVersionData', [{ RegistrationId: 7946531, FacilityCode: 'L' }]);
    expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('getVersionData', [{ RegistrationId: 7946531, FacilityCode: 'L' }]);


});
```

Please help with code.

Comment: why you need the `$rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');`? you already injected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you double inject `$rootScope` 
but the root cause of the problem is that the `$rootScope` is undefined in `it` block, `$rootScope` is defined ONLY on beforeEach closure, you need to define it on `describe` level so it's later available in `it` block

```
describe('whatever', function () {
    var $rootScope = null //define $rootScope on describe level

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$injector_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_; //assign injected $rootScope to the variable from describe so it's available in tests
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    }));
});
```

Comment: still getting error TypeError: $rootScope is not a function

Comment: That's probably because of `$rootScope('getVersionData'` $rootScope is not a function, it's an object

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
```

by

```
spyOn(rootScope,'$broadcast').andCallThrough();
```

Comment: my version is jasmine 2.0